# SAFARI URL encoding

Tags: encoding, safari

The question is pretty simple but is driving me crazy. Using Safari 5+

```
<?
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.es/?parametersandapipe|' ); 
?>
```

The destination URL is encoded to http://www.mywebsite.es/?parametersandapipe**%7C**

Is there a way to prevent Safari to encode characters ??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should encode the URL strings before using them:

```
header('Location: ' . urlencode("http://www.mywebsite.es/?parametersandapipe|") );
```

To parse it afterward, use:

```
$query_string = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

This will ensure that all characters will be "unescaped."

Comment: Parsing it afterwards won't help, since I need the URL to be displayed without encoding.. this solution doesn't work for me..

Comment: Why do you need it displayed in the address bar? All browsers encode special characters, for example, all spaces are converted to `%20`.